# How to get correct values for SRCREV_meta and SRCREV_machine, while applying preempt-rt patch for raspberrypi4-64

Tags: linux-kernel, yocto, raspberry-pi4, yocto-recipe, preempt-rt

I am trying to apply PREEMPT-RT patch using yocto for raspberrypi4-64 machine.

Followed [link](https://lists.yoctoproject.org/g/yocto/topic/meta_raspberrypi_is/96470693?p=,,,20,0,0,0::recentpostdate/sticky,,,20,2,0,96470693,previd%3D1678259358234038513,nextid%3D1677826514566222135&previd=1678259358234038513&nextid=1677826514566222135)

I have done following steps:

- I have downloaded the patch `patch-5.10.83-rt58.patch` from
  [here](https://cdn.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/projects/rt/5.10/older/) and stored
  in `./meta-raspberrypi/recipes-kernel/linux/files`
- I have created a file `linux-raspberrypi_%.bbappend` in
  `./meta-raspberrypi/recipes-kernel/linux`
- I have created a `.cfg` file with `CONFIG_PREEMPT_RT_FULL = y` in
  `./meta-raspberrypi/recipes-kernel/linux/files`
- I have added both patch and cfg file in bbappend using
  `SRC_URI`.
- Also I have done necessary changes into `local.conf`
- Able to select option "Fully Preemptible Kernel (Real-Time)" using command  bitbake `linux-raspberrypi-rt -c menuconfig`
- When I run command `bitbake core-image-minimal`, then it is giving below error:

```
ERROR: linux-raspberrypi-rt-1_5.10.83-r0 do_kernel_version_sanity_check: Package Version (5.10.83) does not match of kernel being built (5.10.110).
```

- I have question regarding .bb file. Currently I have set SRCREV_meta:

```
SRCREV_meta ?= "${AUTOREV}"
SRCREV_machine ?= "${AUTOREV}"
```

- As I read, `SRCREV_meta` and `SRCREV_machine` are git commit values but from where to get those values correctly. Please let me know.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: These git revisions correspond to the `SRC_URI` variables. In the same recipe somewhere you should have an `SRC_URI` variable that has `name=meta` and another with `name=machine` parameters (note that they match the `SRCREV_xxx` postfix). Checking those repositories would give you the applicable commit hashes.